# Android Google Maps: Is it possible to draw map beyond the view limits?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am using a MapView inside a fragment. This view currently is bounded by several peripheral views(like TextView, Buttons etc).

What I want is to show my map in the regions beyond the demarcated MapView without extending the boundaries of the MapView. Is this possible? If so then how?
**Edit:** Currently it looks like this - [The blue bounding bar represents the limit of the MapView ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AzqX.png

I want the map to fill the regions below & at the side of the button without extending the boundaries of the MapView than which it is at present.
Layout code:`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/rideButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textWrapper"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rideButton">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/posReference"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/centerMarker"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_marker"
        android:layout_above="@+id/posReference"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/textWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="TextView 1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_small" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/srcFrag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/short_map_place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="TextView 2"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Light"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_small" />

            ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:tint="@color/white"  />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:foreground="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

`

Comment: Can you show what it looks like currently, and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Can you share your layout?

Comment: Shared the layout code

Comment: Use a framelayout and put the button on top of the mapview

Comment: Putting the button on top of mapview requires me to extend the boundaries of mapview to the bottom of screen which I do not want. I want the boundary of the mapview to remain above the button & at the same time want my map to fill the screen entirely.

Comment: I really don't understand. You want the map to stay the same size, yet make it bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to put "padding" in the MapView.
The advice to use the frame layout is correct (you can't otherwise extend the map outside the physical boundaries of the view).

What you need in addition is to set a "Map padding" that will reduce the view area when doing zoom etc...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding

I'm giving you the URL with documentation and no code because the .setPadding function requires Pixels (pay attention!) so you have to check with different devices and densities how many pixels to put as padding.

You can set padding differently for top,left,right and bottom.

Comment: Map Padding solved my problem. One more thing: when during the life-cycle should I set map padding? It ain't working when I set it inside onMapLoadedCallback but works when say I incorporate a button to set the padding.</p>
I know this can be asked as a different question but if you could answer here, it will be helpful.

Comment: It should work whenever you call it after map is loaded or rendered first time...

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout`

Example-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content -->
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- "Loaded" flash bar layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FlashBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp">
    <!-- flash bar content -->
</FrameLayout>
<!-- Last loaded time layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/UpdateTimeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp" /></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Although this is visually what I want but it does not solve my problem. I want the Mapview to visually fill the screen but its physical boundaries in layout should be aligned to the top of the button and to the bottom of 'textwrapper' (Table Layout id)